# Different between limit_choices_to and queryset in Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to use `ModelChoiceField` in my `Form`. I familiar with `queryset` argument of this field, but I don't any clue about `limit_choices_to` and different between them.

***So, what is main different between `queryset` and `limit_choice_to` in Django `Form`?***

Comment: This doc may helpful you [**limit-choices-to**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)     

[**queryset**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: I had read‌ this doc @RiyasAc

Comment: it will go to filter the given queryset by limit_choices_to.

Comment: Why we use that if we can create `queryset` with that filter? @Blackdoor